# Quarkus 2.1.1.Final java.util.NoSuchElementException: SRCFG00027: Could not find a mapping for

Tags: quarkus

I am developing a proof of concept using Quarkus 2.1.1.Final and the following extensions:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-config-yaml</artifactId>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.smallrye.config</groupId>
      <artifactId>smallrye-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-credentials</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-flyway</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-oracle</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-agroal</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-h2</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-test-h2</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

When I executed *mvnw test*, it's getting the following exception for getting configuration mapping: **java.util.NoSuchElementException: SRCFG00027: Could not find a mapping for**. For configuration definition, I'm using **@ConfigMapping(prefix="...")** annotation.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------< org.examples.quarkus:quarkus-config2 >----------------
[INFO] Building quarkus-config2 1.0.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:2.1.1.Final:generate-code (default) @ quarkus-config2 ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ quarkus-config2 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ quarkus-config2 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:2.1.1.Final:generate-code-tests (default) @ quarkus-config2 ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ quarkus-config2 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ quarkus-config2 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ quarkus-config2 ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running org.examples.quarkus.configuration.ConfigurationTest
18:15:48:830 INFO  (build-56) [i.q.f.FlywayProcessor] Adding application migrations in path '/D:/desa/eclipse-dev/quarkus-config2/target/test-classes/db/migration-test/' using protocol 'file'
ago. 09, 2021 6:15:50 P. M. org.examples.quarkus.configuration.MdPConfigurationMapping
ERROR: Getting MdP Configuration Mapping, message:SRCFG00027: Could not find a mapping for org.examples.quarkus.configuration.MdPConfigurationjava.util.NoSuchElementException: SRCFG00027: Could not find a mapping for org.examples.quarkus.configuration.MdPConfiguration
        at io.smallrye.config.ConfigMappings.getConfigMapping(ConfigMappings.java:73)
        at io.smallrye.config.ConfigMappings.getConfigMapping(ConfigMappings.java:63)
        at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfig.getConfigMapping(SmallRyeConfig.java:418)
        at org.examples.quarkus.configuration.MdPConfigurationMapping.getMdPConfiguration(MdPConfigurationMapping.java:16)
        at org.examples.quarkus.secretkeys.MyBbddCredentialsProvider.<init>(MyBbddCredentialsProvider.java:37)
        at org.examples.quarkus.secretkeys.MyBbddCredentialsProvider_ClientProxy.<init>(MyBbddCredentialsProvider_ClientProxy.zig:28)
        at org.examples.quarkus.secretkeys.MyBbddCredentialsProvider_Bean.proxy(MyBbddCredentialsProvider_Bean.zig:40)
        at org.examples.quarkus.secretkeys.MyBbddCredentialsProvider_Bean.get(MyBbddCredentialsProvider_Bean.zig:228)
        at org.examples.quarkus.secretkeys.MyBbddCredentialsProvider_Bean.get(MyBbddCredentialsProvider_Bean.zig:244)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl.beanInstanceHandle(ArcContainerImpl.java:433)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl.beanInstanceHandle(ArcContainerImpl.java:446)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ArcContainerImpl.instance(ArcContainerImpl.java:311)
        at io.quarkus.credentials.runtime.CredentialsProviderFinder.find(CredentialsProviderFinder.java:12)
        at io.quarkus.agroal.runtime.DataSources.applyNewConfiguration(DataSources.java:248)
        at io.quarkus.agroal.runtime.DataSources.doCreateDataSource(DataSources.java:168)
        at io.quarkus.agroal.runtime.DataSources$1.apply(DataSources.java:111)
        at io.quarkus.agroal.runtime.DataSources$1.apply(DataSources.java:108)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705)
        at io.quarkus.agroal.runtime.DataSources.getDataSource(DataSources.java:108)
        at io.quarkus.agroal.runtime.DataSources.fromName(DataSources.java:104)
        at io.quarkus.agroal.runtime.AgroalRecorder.agroalDataSourceSupplier(AgroalRecorder.java:30)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.AgroalProcessor$generateDataSourceBeans-109901991.deploy_0(AgroalProcessor$generateDataSourceBeans-109901991.zig:81)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.AgroalProcessor$generateDataSourceBeans-109901991.deploy(AgroalProcessor$generateDataSourceBeans-109901991.zig:40)
        at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(ApplicationImpl.zig:328)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:101)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl.run(StartupActionImpl.java:181)
        at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.doJavaStart(QuarkusTestExtension.java:380)
        at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.ensureStarted(QuarkusTestExtension.java:680)
        at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.beforeAll(QuarkusTestExtension.java:727)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllCallbacks$8(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:368)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:368)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:192)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:78)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:136)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.execute(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:188)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:428)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:562)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:548)
```

In this case, it ocurred when Flyway trough Agroal is trying to authenticate in H2 using the CredentialsProvider implementation defined in the project. The CredentialsProvider implementation is using the configuration application.yaml for getting H2 username and password. This is the initial use case. The target is getting chyper password from configuration file.

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Any chance you can provide a reproducer to look at? Thanks!

Comment: [Zip file with the PoC project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DQAQ095Cn9yC_7Ey0_1grvPcUxG08GOz/view?usp=sharing). @RobertoCortez : If you have any problem accessing to the PoC project, I'll find a new way to share the project with you. Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look.

Comment: I had a look, and unfortunately, it seems that datasources are being initialized before the mappings are added into the Config instance, meaning that they will not be available in a `CredentialsProvider` implementation. I already have a PR that changes this behaviour: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/18497. In the meanwhile, the only option is to retrieve the configuration keys directly. I'm sorry for the inconvenience.